# Diatonic vs chromatic harmonica

Tags: tuning, harmonica

The hohner super chromonica has the pattern

```
Do re    mi fa    sol la    ti do
^     |       ^    |      ^   |      |   ^
 |    v       |    v      |   v     v   |
____         ____       ____     ___
  1             2            3         4    <——Holes
  5            6            7          8
  9           10          11        12
```

The hohner marine band harmonica 
has this pattern  on holes 4,5,6,7 but due to less holes has different patterns 
on holes  1,2,3,4   and on 7,8,9,10

In the lower range there is a duplicate 
note on holes 3,4.  (3 draw is sol.)
 Why wasn’t it made fa?

Answer (score 2):

The low 4 blow notes give you the I chord: 1, 3, 5, 1.

The low 4 draw notes give you the V chord: 5, 1, 3, 5.

Putting in the 4 would give you a rootless dominant 7.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, the prominence and importance of the 5th in pentatonic scales might have something to do with it; as I'm sure you're aware, diatonic harps are also called 'blues harps', and blues music generally focuses heavily on the dominant (and slightly less on the 4th).  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richter-tuned_harmonica):

> Although there are three octaves between 1 and 10 "blow", there is
>   only one full major scale available on the harmonica, between holes 4
>   and 7. The lower holes are designed around the tonic (C major) and
>   dominant (G major) chords, allowing a player to play these chords
>   underneath a melody by blocking or unblocking the lower holes with the
>   tongue. The most important notes (the tonic triad C–E–G) are given the
>   blow, and the secondary notes (B–D–F–A), the draw.

Comment: They are much used for blues but the tuning predates this use